# EDF scheduling: what if a task has missed its deadline?

Tags: real-time, scheduler

I know the tasks won't be schedulable but what if I have to choose  at a certain time between a task which has already missed its deadline and another task with a deadline still ahead. What does the algorithm state in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The one that has missed continues until it finishes its execution. This can lead to the domino effect in EDF.
Check out "Transient Over Load Condition & Domino Effect in Earliest deadline first" [here](https://www.microcontrollerslab.com/earliest-deadline-first-scheduling)

Answer (score 0):

From my search, it haven't seen anyone say anything specific about what happens when a task's deadline is older than the current time. The specific action would be up to the developer, because I don't think that task would be a valid task in a valid schedule. When a task misses it's deadline and is yet to be executed, it should be dropped, when using any valid schedule.

Given that scheduling usually happens periodically, by the time the new schedule is set up, it would have a new deadline or it would have been dropped I believe if the task is aperiodic and has not been submitted again.

[This document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/sched-deadline.html#main-algorithm) about the linux kernel's specific algorithm shows an example and an explanation of one obvious solution by a developer, when the task deadline < current time.